# Linking to a DLL I created

Tags: c, dll, static

I am trying to create my own DLL and then make another project load it statically.
My DLL file contains both a header file (called HelloFunc.h):

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"
{
    _declspec(dllexport) void HelloFromDll();
}
```

And a c file (called HelloFunc.cpp):

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"
{
    _declspec(dllexport) void HelloFromDll()
    {
        printf("Hello DLL. \n");
    }
}
```

After building the project an Object File Library (.lib) was created.
Then, on my other project I tried to link to it statically. 
In linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies I added my library (I put it in my new project's directory) and then in linker -> Input -> Command Line I saw that it actually linked to it.

However, when I tried to call HelloFromDll() function in my new code, an error says that it is not identified. Note that I also included "HelloFunc.h" but an error says that the source file couldn't be opened.

I'm a little lost and don't know what I've done wrong. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You must specify `__declspec(dllimport)` instead of `__declspec(dllexport)` when importing a library.
2. What error message did you received exactly?

[Edited]

1. When you compile a DLL, you specify `__declspec(dllexport)`. When you compile an application that imports the DLL, you specify `__declspec(dllimport)`.
2. The problem is that the compiler cannot find HelloFunc.h: Simply copy HelloFunc.h into your new project's directory.

Comment: 1. Where should I specify it? In my DLL I specified the __declspec(dllexport), should I change it to __declspec(dllimport)? (That doesn't seem right because I am exporting this library). Should I use __declspec(dllimport) somewhere in my client?

Comment: 2. My errors are: - Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'HelloFunc.h': No such file or directory C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\StaticLoading\StaticLoading\StaticLoading.c 2
- 2 IntelliSense: cannot open source file "HelloFunc.h" c:\users\Me\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\staticloading\staticloading\staticloading.c 2
- 3 IntelliSense: identifier "HelloFromDll" is undefined c:\users\Me\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\staticloading\staticloading\staticloading.c 6

Comment: @user3497668 Please do not ask the question in comments to an answer. Detailed error messages need to be in the question

Answer (score 0):

Check that you client & library were compiled in the same mode (debug or release).
This is common bottleneck.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the library is compiled in release and I can't compile the client because of the errors. It seems like I didn't link the library properly, though it does recognize in in the command line so I can't put my finger on the problem.